# jest and npm not running test, just hangs

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I am not familiar with node.js because I am still learning front end, however I have started practicing front end via exercism.com which requires you to run tests through their test suites with npm and jest. So I am really out of my depth and have no one to ask, hoping to get some answers.

I am trying to run the command "npm test" in git bash in Windows 10. It was running fine when I ran the first few tests that only had one test to run because the others were blocked out. When I went to run the tests on all of the conditions, it started to have this issue. I have googled a lot, and here is what I tried:

- updating node
- updating jest
- running -i
- running --runInBand
- running -i *and* --runInBand

It just hangs. The last line looks like this:

> jest --no-cache ./*

The real kicker here: **I can run npm test on any of my previous exercises, and it runs just fine.** I really want to understand the problem here. i don't know what information is necessary to share, so here is what seems relevant:

$ node -v
v11.13.0

$ jest -v
25.5.4

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "exercism-javascript",
  "description": "Exercism exercises in Javascript.",
  "author": "Katrina Owen",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/exercism/javascript"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "jest": "^25.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "package.json"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --no-cache ./*",
    "watch": "jest --no-cache --watch ./*",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint-test": "eslint . && jest --no-cache ./* "
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Here is the testing file showing that there is no "x" in front of test:

```
import { steps } from './collatz-conjecture';

describe('steps()', () => {
  test('zero steps for one', () => {
    expect(steps(1)).toEqual(0);
  });

  test('divide if even', () => {
    expect(steps(16)).toEqual(4);
  });

  test('even and odd steps', () => {
    expect(steps(12)).toEqual(9);
  });

  test('Large number of even and odd steps', () => {
    expect(steps(1000000)).toEqual(152);
  });

  test('zero is an error', () => {
    expect(() => {
      steps(0);
    }).toThrow(new Error('Only positive numbers are allowed'));
  });

  test('negative value is an error', () => {
    expect(() => {
      steps(-15);
    }).toThrow(new Error('Only positive numbers are allowed'));
  });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would I be able to run jest on other programs if it was corrupted? I do have it installed globally, but it runs fine when I try to test other programs, which makes me think it’s not corrupted, but i dont really know

Comment: If you run `npm test` you likely run local Jest so it doesn't matter if you have global one. Try to remove and reinstall node_modules for starters. `running --runInBand` - you said you ran `npm test`, so how exactly this was done? `node -v v11.13.0` doesn't sound like `updating node`, it's not too old but this doesn't matter if it doesn't work correctly with some nested dependencies.

Comment: Again, eslintrc isn't needed in the question but package.json is. If you have Jest config in separate file, it's needed too. The problem is very likely specific to your project, this includes test files that could be messed up somehow and stall Jest.

Comment: Im also having same issue, all tests run fine on linux. But when on windows all test run except 1 file. It just hangs.

Answer (score 2):

Since I stumbled on a similar problem while going through Exercism exercises before I eventually figured it out. It is very likely that there is an infinite loop or a bug on the code you are testing using "npm test", thus the reason for its hanging. At least that was my issue when I looked into the code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31498766)

Comment: It was an infinite loop indeed, thank you.